# snap to road google API with python

Tags: python, google-maps, openstreetmap

I need to use google snap to road in my python code.
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/roads/snap

I see google examples of how to use them only in javaScript.
Where can I find an example for python?

Thanks

Comment: which library you are using for accessing google maps ???

Comment: I am using googlemaps, but I am open to change it to any other library that can do the job.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [google-maps-services-python](https://github.com/googlemaps/google-maps-services-python) client library which supports the Roads API and its Snap to Roads service.

Hope this helps you!